# How to select records which have the highest version without getting the old versions record?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, stack-overflow

> **I have below single table , in which we have same 3 rocords with differnt version, We need to fetch records with their highest version.**

**table**

```
Id  name   value   verion
1   raj    java      8
2   raj    stack     4
3   prem   abc       6
4   raj    google    1
5   prem   pqr       11
```

*and many more like this*

**Output should look like this**

```
Id  name   value   verion
1   raj    java      8
5   prem   pqr       11
```

**I have already tried to find the solution with below Stack over question, but I am using single table, not able to find the solution**

*[Selecting most recent and specific version in each group of records, for multiple groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9430743/selecting-most-recent-and-specific-version-in-each-group-of-records-for-multipl)*

Comment: I am using workbench 8.0 for excuting this queries

Comment: here is the output from workbench '5.7.38-log'

Comment: Get max version per name in aggregating subquery. Get according rows in outer query.

Comment: can you please add the solution, it will be helpful @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using subquery we can find max verion per name.

```
select m.*
from my_table m
inner join (select name,
                   max(verion) as mx_ver
            from my_table 
            group by name
           ) as mx_ on mx_.name=m.name and mx_.mx_ver=m.verion;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/NavF5X_K

Comment: let me try this, will confirm result here

Comment: Thank you so much for the most accurate solution. @Ergest Basha